# Method is slower after memoization

Tags: ruby, algorithm, recursion, time-complexity, memoization

I'm working on the following algorithm problem on Leetcode:

> Given a binary tree, determine if it is height-balanced. For this
>   problem, a height-balanced binary tree is defined as a binary tree in
>   which the depth of the two subtrees of every node never differ by more
>   than 1.

Here's the link: https://leetcode.com/problems/balanced-binary-tree/

I've written two solutions--both of which pass Leetcode's tests. The first one should be more expensive than the second one because it repeatedly scans each subtree's nodes to calculate the heights for each node. The second solution should collect all the node heights into a cache so that the calculation doesn't have to repeat. However, it turns out my second solution is actually slower than my first one, and I have no idea why. Any input?

Solution 1:

```
def is_balanced(root) #runs at 139 ms
  return true if root.nil? 
  left_height = height(root.left)
  right_height = height(root.right)

  if !equal?(left_height, right_height)
    return false 
  else 
    is_balanced(root.left) && is_balanced(root.right)
  end 
end 

def height(node)
  return 0 if node.nil?
  [height(node.left), height(node.right)].max + 1 
end

def equal?(num1, num2)
  return true  if (num1-num2).abs <= 1
  false    
end
```

Solution 2: (edited to include cobaltsoda's suggestion)

```
@memo = {}
def is_balanced(root)
  @memo = {}
  return true if root.nil? 
  left_height = height(root.left)
  right_height = height(root.right)

  if !equal?(left_height, right_height)
    return false 
  else 
    is_balanced(root.left) && is_balanced(root.right)
  end 
end 

def height(node)
  @memo[node] = 0 if node.nil?
  @memo[node] ||= [height(node.left), height(node.right)].max + 1 
end

def equal?(num1, num2)
  return true  if (num1-num2).abs <= 1
  false    
end
```

Because the second solution uses memoization, shouldn't it cut out the redundancies and lower the time expenditure of the program? Not sure what I'm missing.

Also, with memoization this goes from O(NlogN) algorithm to O(N) correct?

Comment: The fewer tests you do the better. `@memo[node] ||= [ ... ]` is usually the most efficient way to test-assign-return in one line.

Comment: This is what profilers are for. Try one!  https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/profiler/rdoc/Profiler__.html

Comment: Can you provide some examples of input?

Comment: @cobaltsoda --I'm not sure if it's possible to copy Leetcode's test cases here. I can link to the problem though! Added in my question.